# how to get variable value from div

Tags: javascript, html

I have the code that is getting the value in the form of get variable.  The problem is that I want now to place the variable into a div (for datetimepicker).  When I put it like that the variable is not passed.  Any help will be appreciated.  My current code below:

Working variable:

```
Start Date: <input type="text" class="date-time-input" name="sdate" id="sdatefield"/><br/>
```

Not working variable inside div:

```
Start Date: <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' name="sdate" id='sdatefield'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#sdatefield').datetimepicker({
                sideBySide: true,
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss', 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What "variable" are you referring to?

Comment: Please explain your issue better so far I get a bit confused what, need to be done.

Comment: calendar is not working when you click on calendar icon, what error you are getting ?

Comment: I'm referring to variable (name="sdate" id="sdatefield"). I'm able to process it using the first snippet of code, but not the second one.

Comment: Calendar is working when I click on calendar icon, but the variable in question is not passed for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

observed that you added `id="sdatefield"` to the `<div id="sdatefield">` rather then `<input id="sdatefield">` which is causing this issue, Because you binding datetimepicker to this input field.

Try like the below

```js
 $(function () {
                $('#sdatefield').datetimepicker({
                sideBySide: true,
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss', 
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.js"> </script>

Start Date: <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' name="sdate" >
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="sdatefield"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried your code, but it is not working. Still sdate is not passed any further. Thanks

Comment: your answer gave me a clue what to change for it to work: <input type='text' class="form-control" name="sdate" id="sdatefield"/> Thanks